# Tracking a Flash banner advert using clickTag and Google Analytics

Tags: flash, clicktag

I'm trying to find out if there is a way of using clickTag and Google Analytics to track outgoing banner clicks. clickTag code:

```
on (release) {
  if (clickTAG.substr(0,5) == "http:") {
    getURL(clickTAG);
  }
}
```

Maybe someone can tell me whether the following would work:

```
on (release) {
  if (clickTAG.substr(0,5) == "http:") {
    getURL("javascript:pageTracker._trackPageview('/somebannerad');");
    getURL(clickTAG);
  }
}
```

but I would ideally like a solution that worked with the standard clickTag code and didn't involve changing any code in the flash file. Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't the publisher for the advertisement track all of these statistics for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: http://doteduguru.com/id1313-google-analytics-tracking-flash.html